# Долгое восстановление Callback кнопки после нажатия в модуле vk_api на python

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, callback

Проблема кнопок `callback` при нажатии быстро обрабатывает и отдаёт ответ, но крутит загрузку около минуты при этом не выдает ошибок. Это фича контакта или проблема модуля **vk_api**.

Код:

```
import json

import vk_api
from vk_api.keyboard import VkKeyboard, VkKeyboardColor
from vk_api.utils import get_random_id
from config import DSN, TOKEN_BOT, TOKEN_API_VK, VERSION_API_VK, GROUP_ID

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token=TOKEN_BOT)

from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType

longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session,  GROUP_ID)
vk = vk_session.get_api()

command = {'start', 'help', 'next', 'back', 'search', 'filter', 'favorites', 'blacklist'}

for event in longpoll.listen():
    print(event)
    if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
        if event.object.message['text'].lower() in command:
            if event.object.message['text'].lower() == 'start':
                keyboard = VkKeyboard(one_time=False)
                keyboard.add_callback_button(label=' ПОИСК', color=VkKeyboardColor.SECONDARY, payload={"type": "search"})
                keyboard.add_line()
                keyboard.add_callback_button(label='⭐ Избранные', color=VkKeyboardColor.POSITIVE, payload={"type": "favorites"})
                keyboard.add_callback_button(label='✘ Чёрный список', color=VkKeyboardColor.NEGATIVE, payload={"type": "blacklist"})
                keyboard.add_line()
                keyboard.add_callback_button(label='⚙ Фильтр', color=VkKeyboardColor.SECONDARY, payload={"type": "filter"})
                keyboard.add_callback_button(label=' HELP', color=VkKeyboardColor.PRIMARY, payload={"type": "help"})

                vk.messages.send(
                    peer_id=event.object.message['from_id'],
                    random_id=get_random_id(),
                    keyboard=keyboard.get_keyboard(),
                    message='Привет, бродяга! Для продолжения работы используй кнопки действия!'
                )
    elif event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_EVENT:
        print(event)
        if event.object.payload['type'] == 'help':
            vk.messages.send(
                user_id=event.object.user_id,
                random_id=get_random_id(),
                message="Справка по командам:\n"
                "help - справка\n"
            )
```

[![Кнопка в правом углу][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rASS.png

Answer (score 0):

longpoll работает так: подключается, крутит загрузку до того как произойдет событие, быстро выдает ответ. По симптомам похоже ВК медленно доставляет сообщение.